# Finding products based on multiple tags

Tags: mysql, sql, database, shopify, mysql-python

I have data of the following format:

```
"products":
{
      "handle": "handle1",
      "tags": "t1, t2, t3, t4, t5"
}
{
      "handle": "handle2",
      "tags": "t1, t6, t7, t5"
}
:
:
100s of products with a unique handle and multiple tags
```

I wish to create a DB using which I can filter products based on multiple tags (for ex. getting all the product handles with tags t1 and t6).

This is actually a Shopify data set that I get when I retrieve all the products. I was able to do this with GraphQL APIs but setting it up on pre-existing huge FLASK based application is getting too messy right now.

Also, there exists a mobile app as well that might fetch data using the same backend APIs. Hence looking to do this with the data that we retrieve using REST APIs and then create a DB with it.

Any suggestions for how should I design a DB for such cases?
Thanks in advance for your help.

PS - I am aware that some-one someday might add a new product with a new tag or even pre-existing tags in Shopify and we would have to update the DB again in that case. Solution for that right now is running a cron job periodically to check if any new product(or tag) is added in Shopify that does not exist in our DB and then update the DB(Could be automated quite easily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty you are having illustrates [why it's wrong to store a comma-separated list in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574), when you want to do queries as if the items in the list are discrete data values.

You should store tags in a dependent table, one tag per row. Using your JSON-like notation:

```
"product_tags":
[
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t1" },
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t2" },
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t3" },
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t4" },
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t5" },
  { "handle": "handle1", "tag": "t5" },
  { "handle": "handle2", "tag": "t1" },
  { "handle": "handle2", "tag": "t6" },
  { "handle": "handle2", "tag": "t7" },
  { "handle": "handle2", "tag": "t5" }
]
```

Then you can use SQL set-based operations to find matching sets, instead of trying to use string functions with difficulty.

```
SELECT pt1.handle
FROM product_tags AS pt1 INNER JOIN product_tags AS pt2 USING (handle)
WHERE pt1.tag = 't1' AND pt2.tag = 't6'
```

Or this alternative:

```
SELECT p.handle
FROM product_tags AS p
WHERE p.tag IN ('t1', 't6')
GROUP BY p.handle
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

This is also called [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is saving tags in different tables, also it is better we don't put id for tags and tagname considered as a primary key.

Here a simple solution for your case [link](https://dbdiagram.io/d/5eff64aa0425da461f04389e)

[image]

Comment: We could do it this way as well. But I guess Bill's answer does it in just one table.

Comment: If you just have one table products name will be repeated and it is not good.

Comment: A product can have multiple tags. So in your middle table, we will be having product_id repeated.

Comment: also Bill Karwin mentioned "You should store tags in a dependent table". repeating product_id which is int is much better to repeat varchar.